# Asymptotic notation for multiple limits

Tags: limits, notation, asymptotics

I'm curious about conventions for asymptotic notation when multiple limits are at play. To give a simple example, let's say I have a sequence of functions $f_n$, with derivatives $f'_n$. Suppose $f'_n$, as a function of $n$, is sublinear. In asymptotic notation, this means $$ f'_n(x) = o(n). $$ Meanwhile, rewriting the definition of the derivative, I could say $$ f_n(x+h)=f_n(x) + hf'_n(x) + o(h). $$ In the first case, the little-o is talking about behavior as $n\rightarrow \infty$, but in the second case it concerns behavior as $h \rightarrow 0$. This is confusing as is, but nightmarish if I try to combine them: solving the second equation for $f'_n(x)$ and substituting in the first, I get $$ \frac{f_n(x+h) - f_n(x)}{h} + o(1) = o(n). $$ This is obviously an inexcusable abuse of notation--it looks like we should be able to just combine the $o(1)$ and $o(n)$ to simplify the equation, but this isn't true. My best attempt to fix the ambiguity above is $$ \left(\frac{f_n(x+h) - f_n(x)}{h} + o_{h\rightarrow 0}(1) \right) = o_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n). $$ The subscripts indicate which variable is approaching its limit for each little o, and the parenthesis indicate that the limit in $h$ is taken inside the limit in $n$. This is unambiguous, but complicated. Is there a simpler convention which still allows me to write concisely with asymptotic notation?